# Retrieve the entire rectangle of a scrollable window

Tags: c, winapi

I'm trying to retrieve the entire rectangle of a scrollable window using the WIN32 API.  I thought that `GetClientRect` would return what I need, but that function appears to return only the current viewport.  Is there a specific function call that returns the entire scrollable region as a RECT or must I call `GetScrollRange` to calculate the region myself?

Comment: I haven't ever experience `GetClientRect` returning anything but the full client rectangle, no matter what overlaps it or if it is fully on-screen.  Are you sure?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't work like that.  As far as Windows is concerned, a scrollable window isn't a small viewport onto a larger region whose dimensions you can set or retrieve, it's just a rectangle with a scroll bar control at the edge.  It's up to you to determine the appearance of the scroll bar by calculating the portion of the notional region that is visible within the viewport provided by the window, and to paint the window contents accordingly.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation, now it makes sense.  I was under the mistaken impression that the client area was essentially a viewport into a larger region, as in your example.

Comment: Actually, there are several possibilities, from a viewport onto a larger region (a single large child control which is moved around), a viewport onto a larger region (many children all of which move in concert), a virtual viewport (child controls are created/destroyed as they come into view), a canvas (drawing occurs within the active area), or a scrollbar can be just a slider input control that doesn't scroll anything.

Comment: @Ben - Are you talking about Win32?  Doesn't sound like it.

Comment: Yes.  See for example ScrollWindowEx which can be used to implement the bulk of the logic for the first two patterns I mentioned.  Note that the larger "content" window is a child of the "viewport" window.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds as if that particular window is using virtual scrolling.  Even `GetScrollRange` doesn't necessarily tell you the dimensions, because there's no requirement that a delta of 1 on the scrollbar equals 1 pixel, in fact in many cases it is one record, one row, etc.

Another thing to try is to enumerate all the child windows, and find the minimum and maximum x and y coordinates (don't forget to include the width and height of each child window).  Of course this won't help if the content is directly drawn and not a hierarchy of windows.